# Graphics3D: Opacity limitations

Tags: graphics3d, visualization, rendering, opacity

Trying to make a better-looking globe model, I start off with something like this

[image]

To enhance the 3D effect, I want the lines further from the eye to be "grayer" than the lines closer to the eye, as if there were a little fog inside the sphere.  I thought I might get there by replacing the great-circles with semi-transparent wafers, but it didn't work. It seems as though I hit some kind of internal limit on the number of semi-transparent objects I can create before they become opaque.

Here is the original code with polygonal great circles (minus the RGB-XYZ axes):

```
ClearAll[e, o, g, ϵ];
e[1] = {1, 0, 0}; e[2] = {0, 1, 0}; e[3] = {0, 0, 1};
o = {0, 0, 0}; g = 1.25; ϵ = 1/10000;
ClearAll[polycircle];
polycircle[n_: 360] := 
  Line@Table[{Cos[2 π i/n], Sin[2 π i/n], 0}, {i, n + 1}];
ClearAll[globeGrid];
globeGrid[bands_: 6, figure_: polycircle[]] :=
  {Table[
    Scale[Translate[figure,  Sin[(k π)/2] e[3]], 
     Cos[(k π)/2]]
    , {k, -((bands - 1)/bands), (bands - 1)/bands, 1/bands}]
   , Table[Rotate[Rotate[figure, π/2, e[1]], k π, e[3]]
    , {k, 0, (bands - 1)/bands, 1/bands}]};
ClearAll[showFrames];
showFrames[figure_:polycircle[]] := Show[{   
   Graphics3D[{
     Opacity[0.05], Sphere[], Opacity[1.0]
     , globeGrid[6, figure]
     }]   }
  , Axes -> True
  , PlotRange -> {{-g, g}, {-g, g}, {-g, g}}
  , ImageSize -> Large];
showFrames[]
```

To improve it, I replace the polycircles with partially transparent wafers, which are very thin cylinders at low opacity:

```
ClearAll[wafer];
wafer[opacity_: 1/24] :=
  {RGBColor[1, 0.71, 0]
   , Opacity[opacity]
   , Cylinder[ϵ {-e[3], e[3]}]
   , Opacity[1]};
```

The results were disappointing

```
showFrames[wafer[]]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** I tried a tube

```
polytorus[n_: 100] := Tube[polycircle[n], 0.01];
showFrames[polytorus[48]]
```

it's too slow to be interactive, but it has a better 3D effect.  Still looking for a better answer.

[image]

Comment: oops, my bad. should have been the constant [3].  fixed in the edit (I snipped this code from another context).

Comment: Why not just `ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[lat] Cos[lon], Cos[lat] Sin[lon], Sin[lat]}, {lat, -Pi/2, Pi/2}, {lon, -Pi, Pi}, PlotStyle -> {Opacity[0.7], White}, MeshStyle -> Black]`? http://i.stack.imgur.com/pPKE6.png

Comment: @Rahul That only gives two levels of effective line color: in front or behind.  I believe Reb.Cabin wants to simulate a volumetric fill.

Comment: ... True, but Rahul's comment is excellent.  I'll wait a few days to see whether something new comes up, then ask that @Rahul promote it to an answer.

Comment: Strange. For me, `showFrames[wafer[]]` gives [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/FkEMv.png), and `showFrames[{polycircle[],waver[]}]` gives [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/r4L1G.png). I think the latter is what you wanted, right? BTW, I'm using version 8.0.0.0.

Comment: (Unrelated: The image upload palette seems to no longer work — updating to the latest version didn't help. Anyone has an idea why?)

Comment: @celtschk -- yes, the second is what I wanted.  Looks like this is a MMA 10 issue (or at least a non-MMA 8.0.0 issue :) and I'll file a bug.

Comment: This apparent limitation is still present in 10.0.2.  This issue needs to be addressed one way or another.

Comment: @celtschk I got the same disappointing result as OP in v8.0.4 and v9.0.1, Vista 32bit. Can this be a platform or even hardware related issue?

Comment: @Kuba I don't see why; blur and opacity are disparate effects.

Comment: @Kuba I do not feel it is enough to close; someone may yet provide a blur-like method.  Perhaps you would like to answer that question with this method?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I don't have nerves to work with 3D and Opacity on my old machine :P (*deleeing old comments*)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about something Image3D-based?

```
grid = First@
   ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[u] Cos[v], Sin[u] Cos[v], Sin[v]}, {u, 0, 
     2 Pi}, {v, -Pi/2, Pi/2}, PlotStyle -> None];

Graphics3D[
 {grid,
  {Red, Thick, Line[1.2 {{-1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}}]},
  {Blue, Thick, Line[1.2 {{0, -1, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}]}, {Green, Thick, 
   Line[1.2 {{0, 0, -1}, {0, 0, 1}}]}, 
  Raster3D[Array[
    UnitStep[1 - Norm[{##}]] &, {100, 100, 
     100}, {{-1., 1.}, {-1., 1.}, {-1., 1.}}], {{-1, -1, -1}, {1, 1, 
     1}}, ColorFunction -> (GrayLevel[0.8, .03 #] &)]
  },
 Boxed -> False]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Edit by halirutan

Let me point out some flaws and probably improve the quality a bit. Therefore, blame me for everything that follows, not Szabolcs.

First of all, fog is usually a global thing which means that the impact on the visibility really depends on the distance to the viewer. If the fog is only visible inside the sphere, then we have things like the top of wireframe which is crystal clear (and an eye catcher because lines meet there) while it is farther away from the camera than the front wire.

Therefore, we might improve the effect by making a foggy cube that is larger than the wireframe so that at least it looks like fog is everywhere from the camera viewpoint.

Another detail seems to be that the gradient with which view is degrading doesn't seem to be enough. Therefore, one could make a cube that has not a constant visual density, but a density that is getting larger in one direction. If we then view the wireframe from the correct viewpoint, it might increase the fog-effect.

Last point, I think fog looks better when it is white, not gray. If we combine all these points and make the wireframe thicker then I get something like the following (I'll append the code at the end):

[image]

There are some points left: Most importantly, I don't think it is appropriate to try to achieve something like this in the *Mathematica* front end. If you need high quality, then create your model and render it with [Blender](http://www.blender.org/features/) (or whatever renderer you prefer).

Finally, I could not get antialiasing working when I combined a `Raster3D` with a normal 3d graphics in *Mathematica*. It seems that this is not working with `Raster3D` or `Image3D`.

```
grid = First@
   ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[u] Cos[v], Sin[u] Cos[v], Sin[v]}, {u, 0, 
     2 Pi}, {v, -Pi/2, Pi/2}, PlotStyle -> None, 
    MeshStyle -> 
     Directive[Thickness[0.005], RGBColor[0, 43/255, 18/85]]];

Graphics3D[{grid, RGBColor[44/51, 10/51, 47/255], Thickness[.01], 
  Line[1.2 {{-1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}}], {RGBColor[38/255, 139/255, 
    14/17], Line[1.2 {{0, -1, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}]}, {RGBColor[133/255, 
    3/5, 0], Line[1.2 {{0, 0, -1}, {0, 0, 1}}]},
  White,
  Raster3D[
   Array[#3 &, {100, 100, 
     100}, {{0, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 1}}], {{-1, -2, -2}, {1, 2, 2}}, 
   ColorFunction -> (GrayLevel[1, .05 #] &)]}, Boxed -> False,
  ViewPoint -> {-3.15, -0.89, 0.84}, ViewAngle -> 0.175]
```

Comment: Cannot rotate it smoothly, it freezes the notebook :(

Comment: @SquareOne The first version I posted did have this problem, but the updated one doesn't, at least not on my machine.  Since there was only 12 minutes between my post and your comment, could you reload the page and try again?

Comment: Yes, it's smooth now ... however there is a really strange and heavy slowdown on my machine paradoxically when I test arrays smaller than `{100,100,100}` ?? The problem seems to start and is the worst with `{50,50,50}` then it gets better when the array gets smaller and smaller -> `{10,10,10}`. It's 100 % reproducible (I start from fresh kernel). There seems to be a lot of disk caching then also ... (My config v10.0.2, OSX10.9.5). Do you get the same ?

Comment: @SquareOne Yes, that's strange.  50 is much slower than 100.  Also on Max, 10.0.2, OSX 10.10.2.  I've only tried 100 before.

Comment: I do not get much of a sense of depth out of this; nearly the entire mesh seems to have the same color rather than the farther part having a thicker "fog" -- only the very edges lighten.  Can this be improved?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Is it a bit better now?

Comment: @halirutan Yes! But you probably want to add a `ViewPoint` to that.

Answer (score 15):

I have to admit, that I only copied your code and tried it without actually reading what you have done, but I guess I can help to fix at least the second image. What you are after is the `"DepthPeelingLayers"` settings that you can access with the option inspector:

[image]

When you raise this number to e.g. 32, the output looks like this

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This can also be done on a per-object basis with [`BaseStyle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BaseStyle.html):

```
Show[
  showFrames[wafer[]],
  BaseStyle -> RenderingOptions -> {"DepthPeelingLayers" -> 32}
]
```

Comment: Wonderful!  I knew *someone* would know what was going on.

Answer (score 7):

You just need to change the parameters before and after your Sphere[] like this:

```
{Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.6], GrayLevel[1], Sphere[], GrayLevel[0], Opacity[1.0], globeGrid[6, figure]}]}
```

`Opacity[0.6]` is about right to partly hide the lines around the back.  `GrayLevel[1]` because you want the sphere to be coloured white/light.  `GrayLevel[0]` because you want the globeGrid to be black.

[image: Example with default lighting]

If you don't like the default coloured sphere (I think it's nice) you can fiddle with the lighting, e.g. Lighting -> "Neutral".

Comment: Really nice effect !

Comment: and keeps the rotation smooth. (`Opacity[1.0]` could be omitted.) You should include a screenshot.

Comment: I agree, Opacity[1.0] can be omitted but it is useful to understand that it will be propagated.

Comment: I'm afraid this isn't what OP wants, he wants "the lines further from the eye to be "grayer" than the lines closer to the eye, as if there were a little fog inside the sphere", while this only differs "front" and "behind".

Comment: This is not what I started the Bounty to address, and as @xzczd comments it is not exactly the effect that the OP was after, but +1 nevertheless for an interesting contribution.