# Graphics3D opacity of lines

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphics3d

I would like to make the lines opaque for a plot of form similar to:

```
Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.1], Line[RandomVariate[
    MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0, 0}, {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}], 1000]]}]
```

[image]

Using opacity here doesn't seem to produce a similar effect to using an equivalent for a 2d ListPlot, where it is easier to see the layering.

```
ListLinePlot[
 RandomVariate[MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, {{1, 0}, {0, 1}}], 
 1000], PlotStyle -> {Opacity[0.4], Black}]
```

Does anyone know how I can recreate this similar type of effect with the 3D plot of a line?

[image]

Comment: Works fine for me on MMA 10.0.1.0. You'll probably need to add some info about your system.

Comment: Maybe I should try updating my Mathematica. At the moment am using: "10.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (September 9, 2014)"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This also works for me in 10.1.0 under Windows 7 x64.  Take a look at your rendering settings; referencing [Graphics3D: Opacity limitations](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/55174/graphics3d-opacity-limitations/73857#73857) this is affected by DepthPeelingLayers for example.

```
plot = Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.1], 
    Line[RandomVariate[
      MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0, 0}, {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}], 1000]]}];

Table[
   Show[plot, BaseStyle -> RenderingOptions -> {"DepthPeelingLayers" -> n}],
   {n, {1, 5, 10, 20, 40, 80}}
] ~Partition~ 3 // Grid
```

[image]

Perhaps your rendering hardware simply doesn't support this method, or perhaps `"Software"` rendering is being used.  Try specifically:

```
Table[
  Show[plot, BaseStyle -> RenderingOptions ->
   {"Graphics3DRenderingEngine" -> method}],
 {method, {"HardwareDepthPeeling", "BSPTree", "Software"}}
]
```

[image]

Note that on my system `"Software"` produces a result not too dissimilar to the one you are experiencing.