# How to make lines more smooth in Graphics3D?

Tags: plotting, smoothing

I drew using `Graphics3D`, but I found the quality of output is very low, like this:[image: output].

I wanted to improve the quality of the output, make it more smooth. But I can't find relative options in Wolfram Renference. I know I can use `PlotPoints` in `Plot`, are there some options to do that?

Comment: Edit / Preferences / Appearance / Graphics

Comment: Perhaps also see: [(15735)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15735/121), [(55174)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/55174/121), [(104439)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/104439/121)