# How can I see through more than 2 surfaces?

Tags: plotting

When graphing surfaces with low opacity, I noticed that I can see through  2 surfaces.  However, at most, I can only see through 2 surfaces.  This is perfect if I can graphing 3 surfaces one inside each other.

However, if I am graphing 4 surfaces each inside of the other, the inner most surface cannot be seen.  Try this example below.  Is there a way to make that inner most surface visible?

```
SphericalPlot3D[{1, 2, 3, 4}, {θ, 0, Pi}, {ϕ, 0, 2 Pi},
 Mesh -> None,
 Boxed -> False,
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0},
 PlotStyle -> {Opacity[.1]}]
```

Comment: Is this the answer? http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/73857/5478

Answer (score 3):

Works for me (MMA 10.3 on OSX 10.10.5):

[image]

Comment: Strange.  I am running 10.3 as well on same operating system.  Maybe there is a setting I am missing.