# How to make this 3D animation

Tags: graphics3d, animation, generative-art

How to make an animation of following gif by using  *Mathematica*?

[image]

Comment: Which features of this example are essential to consider an answer a good one?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the new `RandomPoint`- function to sample points from a sphere and use the second argument of `Text` to position some text in 3D. `Text` will automatically make the string face towards the viewer/camera for you.

```
pts = RandomPoint[Sphere[{0, 0, 0}], 100];
Text["test", #] & /@ pts // Graphics3D[#, SphericalRegion -> True, Boxed -> False] &
```

[image: gif]

---

Another approach is instead of rotating the entire graphic (as done above) to rotate the points themselves via `RotationTransform`. This enables the use of coordinate dependent color and size. An appropriate transformation could be

```
r[angle_?NumericQ, pivot : {_, _}] := RotationTransform[angle Degree, pivot];
```

and can be used as follows to archive something closer to what you are looking for with color and size scaling done in respect to the *y*-coordinate

```
Graphics3D[(Style[Text["test", #], FontSize -> 14 - 5*(#[[2]] + 1), 
FontColor -> Blend[{Black, White}, #[[2]]]] & /@ 
r[0, {{0, 0.2, 1}, {1, 0, 0}}] /@ pts), BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, 
Boxed -> True, Axes-> True, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}]
```

[image: picture2]

This can be animated for instance like this

```
Animate[Graphics3D[(Style[Text["test", #], 
FontSize -> 14 - 5*(#[[2]] + 1), 
FontColor -> Blend[{Black, White}, #[[2]]]] & /@ 
r[angle, {{0, 0, 1}, {0.2, -1, 0}}] /@ pts), 
BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, SphericalRegion -> True, Boxed -> False, 
ViewPoint -> Front], {angle, 0, 360}]
```

[image: final result]

To archive your desired look you might have to play around a bit with the color- and size scaling

Comment: Haha, I got that far. Now how to make it smaller and more transparent the further away it is?

Comment: @Quantum_Oli and Sascha, there is a better one but this one is also related to that problem: [55174](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/55174/5478)

Comment: but I need to rotate graphic without click on.

Comment: @Kuba I remember seeing that one the other day and it crossed my mind when reading this question. However I think even if one has a sphere (or ball) in place with the correct transparency options, the `Text` objects ignore it and are always drawn on top. I briefly wondered about converting the `Text` to `FilledCurves` to attempt to circumvent this but I don't think `Graphics3D` accepts `FilledCurves`.

Comment: @Quantum_Oli Use `Inset` then.

Comment: I need another -1 vote on the question... and +18 votes on my answer ...please?:)

Comment: Going for the Reversal age? Good luck.

Comment: @m_goldberg That was actually more intended as a joke. What bothers me a bit about this kind of questions is that answering them can be fun however discouraged the questions themselves are.