# Weird Problem about Inset in 3-D graphics

Tags: graphics3d

I'm trying to answer [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/127417/how-to-make-this-3d-animation) where I want to add text covered by a certain opacity region in 3-D to realize the whitened effect.

But to do this, I need to position Text in certain places and avoid them to be rendered first, so I used the techniques given [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4833/covering-up-text-in-graphics).

While in normal cases this technique works fine:
[image: fine]

when there's a `Raster3D` on scene, all `Inset`s get covered completely while they should be visible but normal `Graphics3D` primitives are all correctly rendered.

[image: wrong]

How can I fix this problem? Thanks!

Note that I want an implementation using `Text`, not `FilledCurve`s as they would rotate with the reference frame and using `Dynamic` with `FilledCurve` is much too resource consuming (If this could be done efficiently, then fine still, just worried about efficiency).

Test code:

```
Graphics3D[{Opacity@1, Specularity@0, 
  Raster3D[ConstantArray[{1, 1, 1, .1}, {20, 20, 
     20}], {{-1.1, -1.1, -1.1}, {1.1, 1.1, 1.1}}], Opacity@1, 
  Table[Inset[
    Graphics[
     Text[Style["test", 
       Blend[{Green, Orange}, {(1 - x)/2, (1 + x)/2}]]], 
     ImageSize -> Small], {x, 0, 0}], {x, -1, 1, .2}], 
  Table[{Blend[{Red, Blue}, {(1 - x)/2, (1 + x)/2}], 
    Ball[{0, 0, x}, .04]}, {x, -1, 1, .2}]}, 
 Lighting -> {{"Ambient", White}}, Boxed -> False]
```

---

## Edit 1

A possibly more significant bug found by @happy fish:

Add `Opacity@0,Ball[],Opacity@1` to the code, then the opacity of `Inset`s works fine, however, mma gets extremely sluggish when evaluating this or dragging the graphics, sometimes return a totally black image.

**WARNING: SAVE EVERYTHING IN MMA BEFORE EXECUTING THIS CODE!!!**

Comment: Observation: add any graphics primitive with non 1 opacity (should be 0 to produce the desired result) will make the text appear (e.g. add `Opacity[0], Ball[]`), however, the resulting graphics can freeze Mathematica. __Save all your work before trying this__.