# Fog effect in Graphics3D

Tags: graphics3d

Can I create fog effect in Graphics3D in such way that the far objects will be lighter and more blurred? Sorry I cannot provide any code since I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: Related: [How to create blurred Graphics3D objects?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6242/how-to-create-blurred-graphics3d-objects)

Comment: I think [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/73933/484) is a more relevant previous post. Regarding code, you could provide an example `Graphics3D` scene to which fog should be added.