# How to recreate this 3D plot?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, image, machine-learning, inset

In other languages, one can make a FeaturePlot3D-esque graphics where the inset images look realistically three dimensional. Meaning that they are smaller when farther away (and also hazier).

So **how can we exactly recreate this clustering of mnist:**

[image]

Is there a way to recreate this effect in `Graphics3D` or `FeaturePlot3D`? Even trying the naive example above actually makes the front-end hang:

```
FeatureSpacePlot3D[ResourceData["MNIST"][[All, 1]], Method -> "TSNE"]
```

Comment: You can get a better sense of geometrical perspective by adjusting the effective viewing distance, e.g., between `Viewpoint -> {1,1,1}` and `{10,10,10}`.  *Mathematica* does not render lighting and shadows, so you'll never get the kind of realism of software designed for true computer graphics.

Comment: Considering view point as a minor part, it looks like a duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/55174/5478, do you agree?

Comment: So you've found time to set a bounty but not to respond to my comment. Which is confusing because that would clarify what is a valid answer here.

Comment: Is it about the performance? What is missing?

Comment: It's about being able to recreate the exactly styling and look

Comment: @Kuba sorry I missed your comment! So the beautiful plot shown above has a depth and a feel (which is lacking in FeatureSpacePlot3D) that I would like to be able to recreate - I'm sure this can be partially done with texture and view angle, but I was hoping for an inspiring answer...

Comment: If you stack a `Image3D` instance with `Graphics3D`, it will emulate fog effect. It was asked before, I but forgot where.

Comment: Put an `InfinitePlane` colored like `GrayLevel[0, .1]` in the y-z plane and you can make this type of thing happen I think.

Comment: @kh40tika Cool! Indeed, that "works". But it is awfully slow... =/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
data = RandomSample[ResourceData["MNIST", "TestData"], 1000];
pts = DimensionReduce[data[[All, 1]], 3, Method -> "TSNE"];
imgs = data[[All, 1]]; classes = data[[All, 2]]; pr = MinMax /@ Transpose[pts];
mm = MinMax[(1/EuclideanDistance[{pr[[1, 2]], pr[[2, 1]], pr[[3, 2]]}, #]) & /@ pts];
vp = {1.3`, -2.4`, 2.`}; vp = {0, -2, 2};
ir[pt : {x_, y_, z_}, img_, class_] := {Opacity[1], 
   Glow[ColorData["Rainbow"][(class + 1)/10.]], 
   Texture[ImageMultiply[img, ColorData["Rainbow"][(class + 1)/10.]]], EdgeForm[{Thin}], 
   Tooltip[GeometricTransformation[
     GeometricTransformation[GeometricTransformation[
       Polygon[{{-1, -1, 0}, {1, -1, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {-1, 1, 0}}, 
        VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0,
           0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}], 
       TranslationTransform[{x, y, z}]], 
      RotationTransform[45 \[Degree], {1, 0, 1}]], 
     ScalingTransform[{1, 1, 1}]], pt]};
g = Graphics3D[MapThread[ir, {pts, imgs, classes}],
  ImageSize -> 400, Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}]
```

[image]

Comment: What about the cloudiness? And smooth framerates?

Comment: That’s currently beyond Mathematica’s abilities, this is the best you’ll get

Answer (score -3):

The simple way is combination of some 3D objects by `Show` like following:
1. Lets make the 3D-shift functions defining the positions of objects in joint figure (+-0.25 in X-direction and 0.25 in Y-dir.):

```
shift = {#[[1]] + 0.25, #[[2]], #[[3]]} &;
shift2 = {#[[1]] - 0.25, #[[2]] + 0.25, #[[3]]} &;
```

Next, let's take the samples of 3D shapes from Wolfram:

```
sample1 = shift /@ ExampleData[{"Geometry3D", "StanfordBunny"},"VertexData"];
sample2 = shift2 /@ ExampleData[{"Geometry3D", "Cow"}, "VertexData"];
```

And draw them:

```
Show[
 ListSurfacePlot3D[sample1, MaxPlotPoints -> 50, PlotStyle -> Red],
 ListSurfacePlot3D[sample2, MaxPlotPoints -> 55]
 ]
```

[image]

Sorry, but cow looks ill :)

Comment: The cow looks less ill when you use the respective `MeshRegion`s: `Show[
 MeshRegion[
  Translate[
   ExampleData[{"Geometry3D", "StanfordBunny"}, "MeshRegion"],
   {0.25, 0., 0.}
   ],
  MeshCellStyle -> {{2, All} -> 
     Directive[FaceForm[ColorData[97][4]]]}
  ],
 MeshRegion[
  Translate[
   ExampleData[{"Geometry3D", "Cow"}, "MeshRegion"],
   {-0.25, 0.25, 0.}
   ],
  MeshCellStyle -> {{2, All} -> 
     Directive[FaceForm[ColorData[97][1]]]}
  ]
 ]`. But I doubt that this will answer OP's question.

Comment: Mathematica also has built in commands for coordinate transformations, like [`Translate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Translate.html).

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher, The perspective can be added directly clicking onto the plot. All rest looks like described in OP.

Comment: @Rom38 I guess, OP's question was more about the fog. That's funny because we all remember these 3D-games from the 90s where all this fog was necessary only because of poor hardware. ^^